# Webm-tools issue with setting up

Tags: cmake, webm, mpeg-dash

I have been trying to set this up for half a day now and I am getting desperate, please help.
I am following https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/DASH_Adaptive_Streaming_for_HTML_5_Video but I am stuck at the step 3 because I am unable to set up dash_manifest (which comes from webm-tools). Error I am getting when I run cmake path/to/webmtools is:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (add_executable):
  add_executable cannot create target "webm_info" because another target with
  the same name already exists.  The existing target is an executable created
  in source directory "/home/relja/Desktop/applicationsAndServices/libwebm".
  See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:31 (target_link_libraries):
  Attempt to add link library "webm" to target "webm_info" which is not built
  in this directory.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/relja/Desktop/applicationsAndServices/webm-tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/relja/Desktop/applicationsAndServices/webm-tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

As I previously mentioned I used libwebm for step 2 of the process.
I have tried removing libwebm for which I get response that libwebm doesn't exist so the operation can't be performed. I have tried playing around with CMakeLists.txt but achieved nothing since I don't understand the underlying cause here. Documentation does not exist (or I couldn't find it) so I had to resort to this. If I forgot to add something, please ask.

EDIT 1:
I forgot to mention, I am using ubuntu
EDIT 2:
Avoided the problem by using unix makefile instead of cmake, works fine

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while fiddling with this and came up with a working CMakeLists.txt:

```
##  Copyright (c) 2015 The WebM project authors. All Rights Reserved.
##
##  Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license
##  that can be found in the LICENSE file in the root of the source
##  tree. An additional intellectual property rights grant can be found
##  in the file PATENTS.  All contributing project authors may
##  be found in the AUTHORS file in the root of the source tree.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(WEBMTOOLS)

set(WEBMTOOLS_SRC_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
# TODO(tomfinegan): The libwebm source directory must be configurable.
set(LIBWEBM_SRC_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libwebm")
# This is where LIBWEBM targets are built.
set(LIBWEBM_BUILD_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libwebm_build")

# Libwebm section.
# Add the libwebm CMakeLists.txt and set the binary dir to allow access to
# libwebm build output.
add_subdirectory("${LIBWEBM_SRC_DIR}" "${LIBWEBM_BUILD_DIR}")
include_directories("${LIBWEBM_SRC_DIR}"
                    "${WEBMTOOLS_SRC_DIR}/shared")

add_executable(dash_manifest
  "${WEBMTOOLS_SRC_DIR}/shared/indent.cc"
  "${WEBMTOOLS_SRC_DIR}/shared/webm_file.cc"
  "${WEBMTOOLS_SRC_DIR}/shared/webm_incremental_reader.cc"
  "${WEBMTOOLS_SRC_DIR}/webm_dash_manifest/adaptation_set.cc"
  "${WEBMTOOLS_SRC_DIR}/webm_dash_manifest/dash_model.cc"
  "${WEBMTOOLS_SRC_DIR}/webm_dash_manifest/period.cc"
  "${WEBMTOOLS_SRC_DIR}/webm_dash_manifest/representation.cc"
  "${WEBMTOOLS_SRC_DIR}/webm_dash_manifest/webm_dash_manifest.cc")

target_link_libraries(dash_manifest LINK_PUBLIC webm)
```

In order to compile webm_dash_manifest:

```
cd webm_dash_manifest/
make
```

Please note also that sample_muxer is now known as mkvmuxer_sample.

Comment: Great, I have solved my problem long time ago (I just needed this for an experiment), mentioned in second edit.
You could notify people working on https://github.com/webmproject/webm-tools about this too.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't responding to assist you (because you indicated that you've already solved the issue), but to assist anyone else who might come across this question.